# How can I dynamically change the background height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to change my background height in CSS dynamically. I have a background that stays in place as I scroll down. So when I use a taller browser window I would like it to zoom in on my background so that there isn't a gap beneath it. My CSS is:

```
body {
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("Photos/Tiger-4.jpg");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[How it should look [Img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITQ9H.jpg)

[What it looks like in a tall browser [Img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euC8W.jpg)

In this second image you can see that there is a white gap underneath the background. I want it to zoom in on the picture instead so that it looks good on phones. So I want the background height the same as the window height, and the width to change appropriately to not stretch it.

I have tried:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

This just made the background stupidly large.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/VpGXJQ) is a demo of something similar. Setting a `vh` (view height) and `cover` on the background-size should fix your issue. The [article](https://www.taniarascia.com/background-position-fixed-and-cover-with-css/) goes a little more in depth.

```
div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 90vh; // or whatever size you want it to be
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` meassure, like this:

```css
div{height: 100vh;
background-image: url("http://e03-elmundo.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2015/11/13/14474300157302.jpg")
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
My text
</p>
</div>
```

but this is just only  a way. If this doesn't fit to you, you can set teh `body` and `html` as the desired tag `height` to `100%` and you will get a similar effect.

Other possible option is using JS to find the screen height and then set the desired size in your tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `aspect-ratio` in your `@media` queries and change the `background-position` as needed.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://elelur.com/data_images/mammals/tiger/tiger-06.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 3/1)  {
  body {
    background-position: center 20%;
  }
}
```